# Why did the last episode of "Star Trek: Picard" hint that Seven of Nine is a lesbian when she was married to Chakotay at the end of "Voyager"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-picard, romantic-interest, seven-of-nine

In the closing moments of the last episode of *Star Trek: Picard*, the show hinted that Seven of Nine was interested in a lesbian relationship with the other woman on the ship. But in the last episode of *Voyager*, it was stated that she had married Commander Chakotay. Is he dead or are they divorced or separated?

Comment: The Picard series takes place after 2009 _Star Trek’s_ supernova destroys Romulus and explains the exploding star’s effect on the Prime universe, where it alters the life of Picard and others in the original timeline. Seven of Nine observed Picard spearhead a rescue mission to evacuate the doomed planet as well as the Federation subsequently abandon the effort, Picard withdraw to quiet life on his vineyard — these events have so impacted Seven of Nine that it’s caused her to re-evaluate the meaning of life and love, and consequently profoundly changing her from her pre-2009 nature. Maybe?

Comment: Sexuality evolves over one's lifetime. Sometimes that takes the form of a shift in orientation.

Comment: To be honest, I think the whole question is founded on a misunderstanding about the existence of bisexual people, based on the wording.

Comment: I think a lot of people are focusing on the wrong part of the question, seems like the OP means to ask....what happened between Chakotay and Seven what made them no longer be together?

Comment: I know several bisexual people, and the idea of moving from a boyfriend to a girlfriend or vice versa is as normal for them as starting up a new relationship is for anyone else. So maybe Seven is bisexual, or maybe she has been gay all along but just didn't realize it.

Comment: ['*Jeri Ryan Says Star Trek's Hot Lesbian Couple Was Created By Accident*'](https://www.out.com/television/2022/3/03/jeri-ryan-says-star-treks-hot-lesbian-couple-was-created-accident)

Answer (score 26):

The present-day versions of Seven and Chakotay weren't married in the final episode of *Voyager*, "[Endgame](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Endgame_(episode))"; they were only dating at the time. It was revealed that they *later* married in the alternate future [Admiral Janeway](https://moviemorgue.fandom.com/wiki/Kathryn_Janeway_(future)) time-travelled back from, and that Seven died in that timeline.

> ADMIRAL: Seven of Nine is going to die.
>
> JANEWAY: What?
>
> ADMIRAL: Three years from now. She'll be injured on an away mission. She'll make it back to Voyager, and die in the arms of her husband.
>
> JANEWAY: Husband?
>
> ADMIRAL: Chakotay. He'll never be the same after Seven's death, and neither will you.
>
> <sub>[*Star Trek: Voyager* - S07E25-26 - "Endgame"](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/722.htm)</sub>

However, since Admiral Janeway succeeded in her mission to alter history, that alternate future was erased from existence, and there's no indication I'm aware of that Seven and Chakotay actually got married in the revised and currently canon timeline.

---

As for what happened to their relationship, [Seven's page on Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Seven_of_Nine#Chakotay) states the following:

> Michael Chabon stated on his Instagram that, considering the evidence, it was safe to assume Seven and Chakotay's relationship had come to an end by 2399. [[1]](https://www.instagram.com/stories/highlights/18131570680023370/)

Chabon also stated in an interview with Queerty that Seven went on to "explore the spectrum of human relationships" in the years following the end of *Voyager*:

> Same thing with Seven of Nine, having to catch up after such along absence from the human race. If you think about that, it almost seems unnatural that she wouldn’t’ have had partners of other genders. It seems clear she would have. So even if we didn’t see that on Voyager, years have passed. In that time, she’s continued to explore the spectrum of human relationships in a broader way. So in our show, there are echos and implications of that.
>
> <sub>[Michael Chabon is afraid he didn’t make ‘Star Trek: Picard’ obviously gay enough. Really.](https://www.queerty.com/michael-chabon-afraid-didnt-make-star-trek-picard-obviously-gay-enough-really-20200328)</sub>

Regarding the point about Seven "switching sides", the fact that her first romantic relationship happened to be with a man doesn't mean she was strictly heterosexual to begin with. And the fact that she's more recently shown romantic/sexual interest in women doesn't mean she's now strictly homosexual.

Given that she's shown interest in men *and* women at different points in her life, it's more logical to conclude that she's *bisexual*, and likely always was, whether she was consciously aware of it or not.

Comment: To be honest, Mr Chabon's suggestion that someone who has been isolated from the human race for a long time would "clearly" be attracted to both sexes seems strange, too.  She might be, of course, but it seems a bit of a leap to say that you could predict that the weird life she'd led would make her bisexual if she wasn't naturally.

Comment: @A.B. It seems Chabon is of the opinion that everyone would be bisexual if not for socialization.    It seems like a pretty big stretch to make that claim as if it's plainly obvious.

Comment: Also remember that a lot of Seven's story arc is her learning what it means to be human. Learning about (or experimenting with) her own sexuality over time would probably be part of that. On the presumption that the Borg have no need for sex, she is probably starting from scratch when she joins Voyager.